# Finding irreducible elements of the ring of entire functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, ring-theory

What are the irreducible elements of the ring of entire functions ? I cannot find these. please anybody help.

Comment: Well, entire functions with exactly one zero of order one are irreducible: if $f$ is such a function and $f(z) = g(z)h(z)$ is a factorization into entire functions, then exactly one of $g(z)$ and $h(z)$ has a zero where $f$ does, and the other one has no zeros and is therefore a unit. Are these all of them?

Comment: They are exactly those of the form $f(z)(z-a)$ where $a \in \Bbb{C}$ and $f(z)$ is any entire nonvanishing function.

Comment: Please write the complete proof .thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An irreducible element $f$ must not be invertible, so it must have a zero.

Let $a$ be a zero of $f$; then $f(z)=(z-a)g(z)$, with $g$ entire. What should $g$ be if $f$ is irreducible?

Comment: g must be non vaniahing over C.Is it?

Comment: @mathislove It must be invertible, yes.